# Loading data when scrolling down to the bottom of the page works well android devices, but does not work apple devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am using pure javascript to loading data when scrolling over and over to the bottom of the page. My code works well in android phones. But it does not work in apple devices. And i do not know where is problem exactly. Here is my code:

```
let self = this
        this.scrollArea = document.getElementById("scrollable-product-area");
        
        $('#scrollable-product-area').on('scroll', function() {
            if(self.scrollArea.scrollTop + self.scrollArea.clientHeight  >= self.scrollArea.scrollHeight - 0.5){
                if(self.secilenKategori.length == 0 && self.secilenMarka.length == 0 && self.search === ""){
                    self.$store.commit("changePostPage",(self.$store.getters.getPostpage + 50));
                    self.$store.commit("changeScrollPosDashboard", self.scrollArea.scrollTop);
                    self.getUrunList();
                }
                else{
                    if(self.$store.getters.getUrunFilterNumber >= 50) {
                        self.$store.commit("changePostPage",(self.$store.getters.getPostpage + 50));
                        self.$store.commit("changeScrollPosDashboard", self.scrollArea.scrollTop);
                        self.urunFilter();
                    }                  
                }
            }
        })
```

This code inside mounted method. I am sending limits of data and page number to function for loading data.

Comment: So, you're using all three versions of Vue, and React, in this application? Because that's what the tags on your question are telling me...

Comment: Might be better using an intersection  observer rather than calculating the scroll position

Comment: Putting as much tags as possible will not help you get your thing fixed faster, quite the opposite. I'm removing all those non-concerned.

Comment: Is this jQuery?

Comment: Sorry i do not know. Thank you for replies. @Miu yes i am using jquery